# In which browsers are regular expression literals created only once

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm reading through the Javascript Patterns book, and one of their examples regarding the creation of regular expression literals does not appear consistent Chrome version 36.0.1985.125 on Mac OSX.

Here's the example

```
function getRE() {
    var re = /[a-z]/;
    re.foo = "bar";
    return re;
}

var reg = getRE(),
    re2 = getRE();

console.log(reg === re2); //true according to book
reg.foo = "baz";
console.log(re2.foo); //baz according to book
```

In this version of chrome, line one in the console is false, and line two is still "bar"

They then go on to say in ES5 that the literal will create new objects each time.  Does this version of chrome implement ES5? And if so, I thought all browsers were still on 3 minus a few augmentations.

Comment: All modern browsers implement ECMAScript 5. Here's a [reference table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#) for you

Comment: ...however, I just tested that code in IE8, and it doesn't give the result described in the book.

Comment: Haha, sounds like possible errata to me :P

Comment: Could be. I also tested in IE 6 and 7. Same result.

Comment: Ah, here we go. Just tested in Firefox 1 and it provides the result described in the book. So they're not totally off the mark.